# I want to create a table that has multiple rows of the same attribute with a different column

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry I should have been more specific with my question:

This is my current issue

I have a table that has this:

```
Customer_ID        H2_1      H2_2      H2_3     H2_4      H2_5
123                 7         3         13       5         2
456                 7         3         13       5         2
789                 7         3         13       5         2
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
Customer_ID         H2_Code
123                    7
123                    3
123                   13
123                    5
123                    2
456                    7
456                    3
456                   13
456                    5
456                    2
789                    7
789                    3
789                   13
789                    5
```

Comment: Are you *creating* a table with these two columns, as the question title states?  Or are you *querying* one or more other tables to get these results?  It's not really clear what the issue is here.  What specific problem have you encountered?

Comment: @Cid Creating tables does not have any thing to do with rows.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1):

You need `UNION ALL` to combine all columns :

```
SELECT Customer_ID, H2_1 AS H2_Code
FROM table t
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_ID, H2_2
FROM table t
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_ID, H2_3
FROM table t 
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_ID, H2_4
FROM table t 
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_ID, H2_5
FROM table t
```

Comment: @Ciccotelli412. . . This is not right place to comment on this instead you edit the question.

Comment: In what sense did the 'old' version not support cross join !?!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
select Customer_ID, H2_1 as h2_code from t
union all
select Customer_ID, H2_2 as h2_code from t
union all
select Customer_ID, H2_3 as h2_code from t
union all
select Customer_ID, H2_4 as h2_code from t
union all
select Customer_ID, H2_5 as h2_code from t;
```

Note that `union all` requires scanning the table 5 times.  For small or medium sized tables, that should not be an issue.  For larger tables, there are slightly more complicated mechanisms that would only scan the table once.

Comment: How would you do this in 1 scan? Using a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to union the differents queries that fetch each H2_something, then order by customer_id

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
  `Customer_ID` INTEGER,
  `H2_1` INTEGER,
  `H2_2` INTEGER,
  `H2_3` INTEGER,
  `H2_4` INTEGER,
  `H2_5` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tableName
  (`Customer_ID`, `H2_1`, `H2_2`, `H2_3`, `H2_4`, `H2_5`)
VALUES
  ('123', '7', '3', '13', '5', '2'),
  ('456', '7', '3', '13', '5', '2'),
  ('789', '7', '3', '13', '5', '2');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT customer_Id, H2_1 AS H2_Code FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_Id, H2_2 FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_Id, H2_3 FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_Id, H2_4 FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_Id, H2_5 FROM tableName
ORDER BY customer_Id;
```

---

```
| customer_Id | H2_Code |
| ----------- | ------- |
| 123         | 3       |
| 123         | 13      |
| 123         | 5       |
| 123         | 2       |
| 123         | 7       |
| 456         | 3       |
| 456         | 13      |
| 456         | 5       |
| 456         | 2       |
| 456         | 7       |
| 789         | 7       |
| 789         | 3       |
| 789         | 13      |
| 789         | 5       |
| 789         | 2       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xeJCBJ6e3cTN24N4fcpxRg/0)

Answer (score 0):

Note that a normalised schema would typically look something like this:

```
Customer_ID    H2    val    
123             1      7     
123             2      3     
123             3     13     
123             4      5     
123             5      2
456             1      7     
456             2      3     
456             3     13     
456             4      5     
456             5      2
789             1      7     
789             2      3     
789             3     13     
789             4      5     
789             5      2
```